# How to perform page-break dynamically while editing live preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-break

How to do page break while editing a page dynamically? While using @page options, page-break is working automatically. I want to see live preview of page at the time of editing so that page-break will appear & content should go to next page as it exceeds.

See Page Print demo -

```
[https://codepen.io/neha-tiwari/pen/eQMOQG][1]
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479833/how-to-add-page-break-dynamically-while-editing-using-jquery-javascript Why?

Comment: Duplicate question

Comment: deleted old one

Comment: You have div{page-break-after: always;} in CSS already. So just insert </div><div> where you want a page break, no?

Comment: page-break working with div's but problem is I want to make live preview of it , so as soon as page ends , & content is more , it should dynamically add new page; provided size of page is given

Comment: Do you have a working example other than codepen? From all I've seen, web designers use fancy CSS tricks to make it look like a page break, but a web page (media screen) is just that, one page. Maybe add a top or bottom border to <div class="page"> or whatever.

Comment: Or they'll use columns to show what looke like two or three pages. Need a working example, picture or crude drawing of what you want it to look like.

Comment: Improved code using paged media js ,                                                         
added css properties for each page -                          
 https://codepen.io/neha-tiwari/pen/bQKzWm                                            
Need to improve this codepen link. Check out & do upvote !